# How to fail a job in gitlab-ci.yml when certain file exists?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to fail a job in Gitlab Runner if a certain file exists. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

When a job’s exit code is different from zero, it fails.

So something like `if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then exit 1; fi` in the job `script:` section should work.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I modified your script to be: if ( -f "$FILE" ){exit 1};
Before that it was expecting statement block after if. Now the error is

"The term '-f' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
 or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included
, verify that the path is correct and try again"